# Disable OneDrive Office 2016 for Mac

Tags: office-for-mac, microsoft-office-2016

Is there a way to hide the OneDrive option when using the File Open dialog in Office for Mac 2016? I don't store anything in OneDrive, and I always have to switch to "On My Mac", which is irritating when you are constantly doing it.

Comment: Have you tried removing/uninstalling OneDrive yet?

Comment: I do not have OneDrive installed.

Comment: With Office 2013 you just had to force quit OneDrive then drag the OneDrive app to the trash.  It would seem in Office 2016 it's completely different. Almost seems built into Office.  I hope that's not the case!

Answer (score 2):

This helped me:

In the menu of your Office 2016 application, go to *Excel* (or *Word) > Sign out* (just below *Settings*) to log out from OneDrive. Now OneDrive should be gone as a storage option until you log on back to your Microsoft account again using the *Add place* option.

Note: I am using the German version. The English menu entry might in fact not be *Sign out*, but *Log out* or even just *Account*, but it should work as described. (Maybe someone can edit this answer to fill in the correct words.)